# Python 3.4.1 - Elements in Nested List

Tags: python

```
Numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x_list = list(itertools.combinations(Numbers, 2))
x_list = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
```

Now, I want to create a new_list which only contains 1, `[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)]`. Then creating `new_list2` that has two odd numbers only, `[(1, 3), (1, 5), (3, 5)]`.

How should I go about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem you've encountered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter with a lambda :

```
Numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x_list = list(combinations(Numbers, 2))
new_list1, new_list2 = list(filter(lambda x: 1 in x, x_list)) ,list(filter(lambda x: x[0] % 2 and x[1] % 2, x_list))
```

if any number modulo 2 has a remainder then that number is odd, `x[0]` is the first element in each tuple `x[1]` is the second.

Comment: >>> new_list1, new_list2 = filter(lambda x: x[0] == 1, x_list) ,filter(lambda x: x[0] % 2 and x[1] % 2, x_list)<br/>
>>> new_list1<br/>
<filter object at 0x00000000036754E0><br/>
>>> new_list2<br/>
<filter object at 0x0000000003675588><br/>
>>>

Comment: @MarkConcepcion, forgot you were using python 3, filter is an iterator in python 3 so you need to call `list(filter)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension :

```
>>> [i for i in x_list if 1 in i]  #contain_one
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)]


>>> [(k,t) for k,t in x_list if k%2!=0 and t%2!=0] #odd_list
[(1, 3), (1, 5), (3, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [2]: x_list = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]    

In [3]: one_list = [c for c in x_list if c[0]==1]

In [4]: one_list
Out[4]: [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)]

In [5]: odd_list = [c for c in x_list if all(i%2==1 for i in c)]

In [6]: odd_list
Out[6]: [(1, 3), (1, 5), (3, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = [a for a in x_list if 1 in a]
new_list2 = [a for a in x_list if a[0]%2!=0 and a[1]%2!=0]
```

this should work =)